# Add a UINavigationBar to a UIView using Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uinavigationbar, xcode7

I have a modal view that I'm presenting over the current view that has a `UINavigationBar` as a subview. Everything's working great, except that the `UINavigationBar` doesn't want to behave according to the autolayout constraints. Everything else in the view behaves as desired.

For some reason, the left and right bar button items are cut off on the edges of the view. I inspected the view at runtime to reveal that the total width of the `UINavigationBar` is the right width, but the bar buttons aren't conforming.

I also checked to make sure I didn't have negative margins or some other anomaly in the constraint definitions.

I have also tried setting the frame of the `UINavigationBar` manually, but it yielded no improvement.

**Problematic View**

[image]

**Constraints**

[image]

I'd like to keep the `UINavigationBar`, because it gets styled globally with the rest of my app (as opposed to creating a custom `UIView` imitation and styling it individually). Does anyone know what handle to jiggle to get the bar button items to conform to the right width?

Comment: Why is your width 414?  What screen size are you designing for?  What is the width of the superview?

Comment: I'm designing for any screen size. 414 is the width of the view when iPhone 5.5 inch is selected in the "Simlated Metrics" section in the Utilities bar. It *should* update to whatever runtime size based on the constraint.

Comment: It seems that 414 is wider than the superview from your picture.  Also in looking at your hierarchy is the bar supposed to be part of the scroll view?  That seems a bit odd.

Comment: It still has the same issue when I reduce it to the 320 of the 3.5" simulated screen. The view structure belongs to a scroll view to be able to adjust for the keyboard. I also had this same issue before I nested it all in a scroll view.